# LINQ CONTAINS IN C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, contains

I have a linq query like following. It is very slow when `allStudents` contains a large amount of data. I have known from different blogs that `Contains` is very slow. Can anyone give me a better solution to improve the performance.

```
var selectedStudents = allStudents.Where(s => !studentsIdList.Contains(s.Id));
```

Here allStudents is an IQueryable and studentIdList is a List

Comment: How many rows are in the table, how big is studentidlist and how many hits are you getting?

Comment: `Contains` is not slow per se. It depends what collection type you use. For example, `Contains` on a `List<T>` may take an amount of time that is proportional to the number of elements in the list, while with a `HashSet<T>`, it will take a small and almost constant amount of time, no matter how many elements there are in the set.

Comment: About 20k rows and studentIdlist is about 15k

Comment: What is the type and origin of `selectedStudents`? Is it somehow database related?

Comment: Is the data in studentsIdList already in the same database as allStudents? If not the process of sending 15k ids to the database as part of the query will be very slow. You need to do the JOIN in the database.

Comment: We cannot help you with one line of code. Please show us how `allStudents` and `studentsIdList` are populated. If this is a DB query a stored procedure will definitely improve the performance

Comment: @glautrou is right. There may be hundreds of reasons why Contains is slow because we don't even know what class your Contains method belongs to. It can be `List.Contains`, `Enumerable.Contains` or a custom contains implementation of a different collection class. We also don't know what collection `allStudents` is. Is it a local list? Is it an IQueryable? We need these details to provide a valid answer to this question.

Comment: - for not giving details, will give + if you give details

Comment: Since you have updated your question by stating `studentsIdList` is a `List<T>` and `allStudents` is an `IQueryable<T>`, I believe your problem is sending 15k integers to the database for filtering. In this case you should do the join in the database like @James said. (Unless you're asking the client to select 15000 students in your application and do the filtering based on that user input, of course)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you first pull all the students out of somewhere (maybe a db?) and then try to filter them out, which is a bad idea. Instead you should let the database to do the work.

Comment: So he should use stored procedure?

Comment: @stackunderflow No, he should use something like LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities so he can send the query to the database and get only the items he needs instead of getting all items first and _then_ filtering them locally.

Comment: how can use this. Please suggest me @ Safak Gur

Comment: @Azim: What are the types of `allStudents` and `studentsIdList`? I assume both of them are local collections. You should change the way you fill these collections. You get the items from the database, right? Get only the ones you need by sending your query with a filter. How do you access the DB? Do you send the query string manually? Do you use an ORM framework?

Comment: @Azim: Great, and where does the `studentsIdList` come from? Do you get that also from the database? You should edit your question and mention the details (like you are using Entity Framework to fetch the data). How do you obtain `allStudents` and `studentsIdList`? We can help you better if you update your question and provide the code starting from the point you request the data using the entity context. You should also add `entity-framework` tag to your question.

Comment: How can an asnwer beginning by "It seems" and not giving the solution can get +3? @Azim needs to give more details (as I asked as a comment on his question), otherwise there is no way to find the solution

Comment: @glautrou, based on the provided info there's no way to provide a definite answer. I've explained what he should do and it's up to him to do it. The code would be pretty much the same, the whole solution to that is to simply not load all the records, but use the algorithm right on the data store. What's there hard to understand is really a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with large amount of data and when you want to get good performance then get from database stored procedure, because linq will process in memory so it will take more time.

Comment: Unless it is LINQ to SQL, or LINQ to Entities of course, which this could be, the OP isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution in LINQ using an Outer Join and excluding all results where the 'empty' values are 0. Assumes no student will have an ID of zero. For a more complex you should use `p == null`. Would use database  if your source was a database accessed using EF.

```
List<int> allStudents = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List <int> studentsIdList = new List<int> {1,3,5,7,9};

var q = 
        from c in allStudents 
        join p in studentsIdList on c equals p into ps 
        from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        where p == 0
        select new { Student = c};
```

Gives result
2 
4 
6 
8

Comment: Your elegant solution is tempting, but still i wish someone test the proposed solutions here with big data using diagnostics timer

Comment: In SQL terms it's a standard left join using null to filter out the 'missing' items. It's a single call to the database so there is no reason to think it will be slow. Another option is to write it an SQL view then call it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Did u try to get allstudent in one query

Then allstudent to be excluded in another query then iterate on the first query removing the unwanted and compare time and tell us :p

```
var allStudent = allStudents;
Var unwanted = allstudent.Where( s=> studentIdList == s.id);
```

Then

```
foreach( var item in unwanted ){
allStudent.remove( item);}
```

tell us difference in time plz

Comment: This will make it more slower